# showing error message(invalid name or password) in same jsp page is not working

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, requestdispatcher

i have two jsp file **index.jsp** and **login.jsp** and **profile.jsp**.
here index.jsp has two text field name and password.

When I give right name and password login shows successful and go to **success.jsp** but when i give wrong password or name i want that an error message will show in same index page that is "invalid name or pass". my code is not working **login.jsp** is used for username and password authentication..please help me to solve this .

I have searched about RequestDispatcher but it is used in servlet class.but i want to do it in my jsp file.my code

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Example</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="login.jsp">
        <center>
        <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" align ="left">Login Here</th><h5><%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage") %></h5>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Yet Not Registered!! <a href="reg.jsp">Register Here</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </center>
    </form>
</body>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
    <%
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test", "postgres", "root");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from member where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
        //out.println("welcome " + userid);
        //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
        response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
    } else {
        //out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
             }
    %>
```

Comment: why you are using response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); in else condition

Comment: With `sendRedirect` you tell the browser to send a **new request**, i.e. the attributes you've stored into the **current**request are lost.

Comment: for staying in index page after clicking submit button.and pass the values of set attribute to index page..is it wrong process ?because using same process i have passed the user id to my success.jsp page. how may i stay in my index page and show the error message..i have used  RequestDispatcher dispatch=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp"); but not working

Comment: this is not right way. At first you should not use functionalties in jsp page. Use jsp only for displaying purpose and use servlet for handling functionalities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your else statement, don't use `response.sendRedirect()` because all the saved attributes will be lost as it's a new request, use `requestDispatcher.forward()` instead:

```
req.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");
req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, res);
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in your code itself. For success you have used session.setAttribute so its working, and for login failed" you have used request.setAttribute that's why its not working. Go for session rather than request or user requestDispatcher to forward your request. And You have mansion that you used RequestDispatcher but its not working, it will not work unless you write complete statement like calling forward method of requestDispatcher.

Answer (score -1):

you can do in index page in form

```
  <div style="color:red">${errorMessage}</div>
```